# Python: VTK Distances in a TubeFilter

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vtk

I have the follwoing problem. I want to create a Tube with vtk TubeFilter and want to calculate all distances of the points in the tube to the inner line in order to score them in dependence of their distance to the line. Is that possible with some vtk or other method? (maybe  with implicitPolyDataDistance or vtkDistancePolyDataFilter ?)

Best regards

Comment: In my opinion, what you are describing calls for a geometric operation, rather than for a tube filter, which is useful for graphical representation of a tube. I would use vtkLine and the function DistanceToLine to obtain the desired result. If you want to limit the number of points to investigate you could use vtkPointLocator to restrict the DistanceToLine operation to those points that are 'in the neighborhood'.

Comment: But DistanceToLine is only possible for linesegments isnt it? What is with polyline that have several changes in direction? And what exactly does PointLocator do? Best regards

Comment: vtkPointLocator allows you to quickly find a point in the neighborhood of an object. This can be very useful if you have a large number of points, and you don't want to compute the DistanceToLine for each point, but only to those contained in the neighborhood of the line or polyline. <br/> If you're looking for the closest distance of a point to a curved polyline you probably need to loop over all segments of the polyline. I'm not aware of a vtk method that does this.